# ASP.NET Custom Postback doesn't refresh parent control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am doing a custom postback in a user control which in a nutshell I am registering using the following code:

```
public event EventHandler SelectedPersonChanged;

ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
String cbReference = cs.GetCallbackEventReference("'" +

this.UniqueID + "'", "arg", this.UniqueID + "ReceiveServerData", "",
this.UniqueID + "ProcessCallBackError", false);

String callbackScript = "function SelectPeoplePostback(arg, context) {" +
cbReference + "; }";
cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "SelectPeoplePostback",
callbackScript, true);
```

This works fine, it calls the ASP Generated postback function and I can handle the postback in my code. What I am then doing is firing an event in this control, which I handle within the parent control of this control. Via the usal eventhandler:

```
this.SelectPeople.SelectedPersonChanged += SelectPeople_SelectedPersonChanged;

void SelectPeople_SelectedPersonChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectPeople.PeopleID = 0;

        // COMBO BOX NEVER REFRESHES ON UI
        cboProducts.DataSource = dbProducts.SelectProducts(peopleID, peopleID);
        // this should cause a refresh
        cboProducts.DataBind();

        //MAYBE GENERATE POSTBACK HERE ???? TO REFRESH PAGE
    }
```

The PROBLEM

I cant seem to be able to bind a combobox or any UI item in my event handler, now I suspect I need to get the page to refresh somehow, i.e. trigger a postback from parent page that will update the combo the box, but I though triggering a postback from my user control would of took care of this.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the handler to make sure it is being hit?

Comment: Yes its definitly being hit, and populates my combo box, its just that the UI doesnt refresh. its worth noting the control im updating is in the parent control and a child control inits the event. I have even tried event bubbling. Thanks for the EDIT, apologies for my sloppy typos.